# What is the atomic number of a positronium?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, conventions, positronium

Since a positronium has no proton, I would suggest $Z = 0$ but I'm not sure if you can see the electron as the center of mass and therefore $Z = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The atomic number is the number of protons.  Positronium has no protons, so it definitely cannot have a non-zero atomic number.

But positronium is also not an atom and so it cannot even be said to have atomic number number.  It's simply a bound state of an electron and it's anti-particle.

Answer (score 0):

The positronium is technically not an element, it can only be said to be a particle.  This question may not be so physics-related, so please go to the chemistry site and check.